# Yii2 - foreach loop to save all files path in database model

Tags: file, foreach, model, path, yii2

**Greetings,**

i'm using a multiple file upload input in Yii2.
The multiole file input is saving very well the files selected inside a folder called audio.
The problen is i cannot inside foreach loop save the name and path of each file in the database model Faixas.php inside a field called ficheiro.

Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Faixas();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->files = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'files');
        if ($model->upload()) {
            return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

**The Model as a function named upload() to save the files in folder, but the part to save inside the model->ficheiro is not working (don't figure it out ?):**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['nome', 'ficheiro', 'dummy1', 'dummy2', 'dummy3', 'dummy4', 'dummy5'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['files'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'mp3, ogg, webm', 'maxFiles' => 30],
    ];
}

public function upload()
{   
    $model = new Faixas();
    if ($this->validate()) { 
        foreach ($this->files as $file) {
                $file->saveAs('audio/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);

                // this part in not working, why ????
                $filePath = 'audio/'  . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
                $model->ficheiro = $filePath;
                $model->save();
    }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**And finally the view, which renders the input:**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'files[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'audio/*']) ?>

<button>Submit</button>
```

**Any ideas on the way to get it done?
Many thanks...**

**The entire Faixas.php model class:**

```
   <?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
* This is the model class for table "faixas".
*
* @property integer $id
* @property string $nome
* @property string $ficheiro
* @property string $dummy1
* @property string $dummy2
* @property string $dummy3
* @property string $dummy4
* @property string $dummy5
*/
class Faixas extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
 public static function tableName()
{
    return 'faixas';
}

public $files;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['nome', 'ficheiro', 'dummy1', 'dummy2', 'dummy3', 'dummy4', 'dummy5'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['files'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'mp3, ogg, webm', 'maxFiles' => 30],
    ];
}

public function upload()
{   

    if ($this->validate()) { 
        foreach ($this->files as $file) {
                $file->saveAs('audio/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
                $model = new Faixas();
                // this part in not working, why ????
                $filePath = 'audio/'  . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
                $model->ficheiro = $filePath;
                $model->save();
    }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
        'nome' => Yii::t('app', 'Nome'),
        'ficheiro' => Yii::t('app', 'Ficheiro'),
        'dummy1' => Yii::t('app', 'Dummy1'),
        'dummy2' => Yii::t('app', 'Dummy2'),
        'dummy3' => Yii::t('app', 'Dummy3'),
        'dummy4' => Yii::t('app', 'Dummy4'),
        'dummy5' => Yii::t('app', 'Dummy5'),
    ];
}

// coloca o Audio na GridView
public function getAudio()
{
    return \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/'.$this->ficheiro;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED... removed from the model file the rule:**

[['files'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'mp3, ogg, webm', 'maxFiles' => 30],

**Now the foreach() loop saves every file Path in the database.**

Many thanks to all that somehow tried to achieve a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you create the model in wrog place. You create a `$model = new Faixas();` ouuside the loop.  try creating inside.

```
public function upload()
{   

  if ($this->validate()) { 
    foreach ($this->files as $file) {
            $file->saveAs('audio/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);

            $model = new Faixas(); 


            $filePath = 'audio/'  . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
            $model->ficheiro = $filePath;
            $model->save();
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. $model->ficheiro continues empty. :( Thank's for the try.

Comment: It is above the view. Only 2 principal functions. Do you need to see all the file?

Comment: You are mentioned database model, i need to check all the Faixas class Model not only the upload function and rules

Comment: If you can, check the content $model->ficheiro after the assignment ` $model->ficheiro = $filePath;` if is not empty teh problem could be in the `[['files'], 'file',...... ` rules if otherwise is empty the problem could be in the files assignment  (in Create Action)..

Comment: I had to leave computer, but later i will return. Many thanks.

Comment: @scaisEdge awsome! I had the exact same mistake I was calling my constructor out side the loop that is why it was saving the data only once ... you saved me! thanks :)

Comment: @Uzumaky Naruto,It 'was an easy save

Comment: I cannot  check the content $model->ficheiro after the assignment. Tried with var_dump or with echo, but nothing appears. Any suggestions?

Comment: It should contain at least  `'audio/' `. Or you can't check this anyway?. You don't use a debugger?

Comment: SOLVED... removed the: [['files'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'mp3, ogg, webm', 'maxFiles' => 30], and now it saves every file Path.